# What does the operator colon in the satement "export variable=lib:/dev/input/event0" mean in linux environment??

Tags: linux, bash

first time see such statement by exporting a variable. How to use it and what does it mean?

Comment: It _could_ be used a concatenation of paths (same as `$PATH`).

Answer (score 2):

The `:` character itself doesn't mean anything on its own. An environment variable is just that - a variable, either unset or containing some value. The value is then used by another program, so what the `:` means depends on what program is using the variable.

Often it is used as a separator, as with the `$PATH` variable - you list various directories you want checked when you execute a command in a shell without specifying a full path (eg, `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin` - each directory is checked).

In the example you give, `lib:` looks like it might be a prefix of some sort. But in the end, it really depends on what will be using the variable.

Comment: I do know that the colon is used as separator by setting the PATH variable. but I was wondering about using it in this context because `tslib` is the name of the library without colon like in this example `export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=tslib:/dev/input/event0`. I will not have any problem when the full path of library is set then I can treat the colon as a separator as mentioned above. Can't understand why degrading my question.

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer wasn't clear, but I was trying to say: it all depends on what is using the environment variable.